# How to kali linux "poetry run python empire.py server" can working

Tags: python, kali-linux

[image]

I entered

`sudo poetry run python empire.py server`

and it returned

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/Empire/empire.py", line 11, in 
> import empire.server.server as server
> File "/opt/Empire/empire/server/server.py", line 12, in 
> import urllib3
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'

how can I work it?

Comment: `sudo apt install powershell-empire` Note: Kali requires you to run Empire with sudo. https://bc-security.gitbook.io/empire-wiki/quickstart/installation

Comment: https://www.kali.org/tools/powershell-empire/